# Flutter - Rounded corners in SliverAppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter you can have custom shape in **AppBar** widget with **shape** property, but this property is missing in **SliverAppBar** widget

```
  AppBar(
    title: Text('Hello'),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
        bottom: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

how to have **rounded corners** in **SliverAppBar**?

[image]

Comment: yes, AppBar does have property shape

Comment: If the property is missing could you not create your own custom widget using the code available to you?

Comment: what widget would you use to implement scroll parallax?

Answer (score 29):

This is the right and easy way to change the shape of a SliverAppBar **(As mentioned in Flutter docs)**. No need you use any tricks. Even you can shape it as any shape you want.

```
SliverAppBar(
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
  title: Text('Sliver AppBar'),
);
```

Comment: use [RoundedRectangleBorder()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RoundedRectangleBorder-class.html) instead.

Comment: `borderRadius` of `SliverAppBar` is not working on `flexibleSpace`, when expanded.. How to fix this ??

Answer (score 3):

If someone need to add bottom border corners with `SliverPersistentHeader`

In the delegate:

```
Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(15.0)),
  ),
  child: Image()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this kind of design using `BorderRadius` widget.

```
Container(
        height: 75.0,
        child: Center(child: new Text("Hello",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            height: 2.5,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18.0,
          ),
        )),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(blurRadius: 3.0)],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(19.0)),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

**This will not give you parallax scroll functionality**

Comment: as I said, I've already achieved this result (by changing AppBarShape)

Answer (score 0):

```html
 SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                    handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                        context),
                    sliver: SliverAppBar(
                      pinned: true,
                      stretch: true,
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      expandedHeight: 180,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        stretchModes: const <StretchMode>[
                          StretchMode.zoomBackground,
                          StretchMode.blurBackground,
                        ],
                        background: Stack(
                          children: [
                            CustomImage(
                              path: "assets/images/profile.png",
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: iconGreyColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                                bottom: 50,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    CustomImage(
                                      path: "assets/images/notification.png",
                                    ),
                                    Icon(Icons.message),
                                    Icon(Icons.search)
                                  ],
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                          bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
appBar: AppBar(
    shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(100))),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

this property is not  missing in SliverAppBar widget it's like AppBar Widget but you don't need to 'appBar:' property in Scaffold Widget, you need  'body:' property and on it you must add CustomScrollView Widget, and in 'slivers:' property you can add list of Widgets starting from SliverAppBar, and as you like you can add SliverList,  SliverGrid,
I tried that and it's done, this is my code.

```
Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 180,
            title: Text('RoundedRectangleBorder'),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                bottom: Radius.circular(40),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```